# What does it mean to "plug" a gradient?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, notation, mathematics

Researching Cotton tensor I found in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotton_tensor):
$$\tilde{C}=C+\text{grad }\omega\lrcorner W $$ with a comment "where the gradient is **plugged** into the symmetric part of the Weyl Tensor W." What exactly is the operation of "$\lrcorner$"? How do I call it?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136485/what-does-this-symbol-mean-looks-like-a-lower-right-corner-subject-manifol).

Answer (score 4):

In general, "plugging A into B" means that you provide A as an argument to the function B.  In physics, we would usually describe "plugging" the gradient into the Weyl tensor as contracting the index on the gradient with one of the indices on the Weyl tensor.  Remember that a tensor is a function taking vector arguments and returning a scalar, so describing it as "plugging in" makes sense.  In differential geometry, there is a similar ["interior product"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product) — which is just contraction of a vector field with a differential form — and, as the link Cosmas provided points out, is frequently denoted with $\lrcorner$.

Just an extra explanatory note: In GR we usually describe the Weyl tensor as a function that takes four vectors and returns a scalar value.  It is also possible to think of it as a function that takes *two* vectors and returns a linear transformation of the tangent space.  In this case, it is an *anti*symmetric function of those two vectors — and is sometimes described as a "matrix-valued 2-form".  I don't actually understand which "part of the Weyl tensor $W$" could be considered "symmetric" in this sense, and that couldn't be an interior product, since that's just defined on (totally antisymmetric) differential forms.  But in any case, the equation containing the $\lrcorner$ symbol is just a restatement of the equation before it.